# Function of complex conjugate equal complex conjugate of function?

Tags: complex-numbers

Very simply, for what type of functions $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  is the following true?
$f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$

Does Schwarz reflection principle imply this is true for all analytic functions?

Comment: Every $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ will do.

Comment: Might I please see a proof (or link to one) ?

Comment: Ah, just because the conjugate of a real number is again real. :)

Comment: @staple You DO realize that $\bar\cdot |_{\mathbb R} \equiv \mathrm{id}$??

Comment: And I chose to make it a comment instead of an answer because I want to hint you that you may have to put some additional conditions in order to assume away cases of less interest like the one I gave and hence your question can solicit more interesting answers.

Comment: For one thing, ratios of polynomials with real coefficients. But there are many more.

Comment: How about among $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Sorry, did a bad job of qualifying my original question and reading Gudson's reply